# Parse and extract data from a HTML Text

Tags: php, html

I have the below HTML text stored in a variable $domText

```
<TR class="tableclass">
  <TD>Veteran Job Information</TD>
  <TD>9.00</TD>
  <TD>1.2</TD>
  <TD><INPUT type = "text" name = "notes"></TD>
</TR>
```

I want to check if the Text content in the First  (Here "Veteran Job...") is equal to "Benefit Job" then need to store the values in second and third  (Here 9.00 and 1.2) tags to a PHP Variable.

Below is what I have tried to do, But I am getting errors and my code is not working at all.
**"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"**

```
        $dom_ChangeResults = new DOMDocument();
        $dom_ChangeResults->loadHTML($domText); //Load the current changes as HTML String
        $dom_TableTags = $dom_ChangeResults->getElementsByTagName("TR"); //Check table data tags for Full time to PartTime Change
        $rows = $dom_TableTags->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('TD');

        /*** loop over the table rows ***/
        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {
            /*** get each column by tag name ***/
            $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
            /*** echo the values ***/
            echo $cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />';
            echo $cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />';
            echo $cols->item(2)->nodeValue;
            echo '<hr />';
        }
```

Comment: Out of convention, please don't capitalize your `<*>` tags, ie `<tr>` not `<TR>`

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. That's the way it is through out the project. For now, I have to use as it is now and then will fix them in a separate work orders.

Comment: No worries. It doesn't effect anything for plain HTML, but its best to follow common practice :P Also, what happens when you `var_dump($rows)`?

Comment: So, your `$rows` should contain the 3 `TD`s... why then do you do `$row->getElementsByTagName('td')`?  Wouldn't you want to do `foreach($dom_TableTags as $row)`?

Comment: I tried various variations of "TD", 'td' etc. But during debug the LHS variable ($rows) will have nothing in it :-(

Comment: Is that all that's in `$domText`?  Are there `<table>` tags, or just the `<tr>`s and `<td>`s?  If that's the *exact* html you have, then you might not need `getElementsByTagName("TR")`.  This is because when you do `loadHTML`, `$dom_ChangeResults` will become the *root* of the file you gave it.  In this case, it's the `TR`.  So, try this: `$tds = $dom_ChangeResults->getElementsByTagName('td');`.

Comment: I did not wrote the code. I am just fixing a bug. To answer your question, YES, I have copy pasted EXACT contents of my Variable $domText. I just need a way to EXTRACT those TD values to a PHP Variables. ANY method will works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use capitalized tags with PHP DOMElement. Don't know if this is all code that You gave us, but capitalization in PHP script is main issue, `getElementsByTagName('TD')` will return empty list, where `getElementsByTagName('td')` will return populated list.

```
    $dom_TableTags = $dom_ChangeResults->getElementsByTagName("TR"); //Check table data tags for Full time to PartTime Change
    $rows = $dom_TableTags->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('TD');
```

shouldn't this be (or You have just one row?):

```
    $dom_TableTags = $dom_ChangeResults->getElementsByTagName("table"); //Check table data tags for Full time to PartTime Change
    $rows = $dom_TableTags->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

well [here](http://pastebin.com/3tG30cFX) is working sample code

```
$domText = <<<DOM
        <TABLE>
        <TR class="tableclass">
          <TD>Veteran Job Information</TD>
          <TD>9.00</TD>
          <TD>1.2</TD>
          <TD><INPUT type = "text" name = "notes"></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR class="tableclass">
          <TD>Veteran Job Information</TD>
          <TD>9.00</TD>
          <TD>1.2</TD>
          <TD><INPUT type = "text" name = "notes"></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR class="tableclass">
          <TD>Veteran Job Information</TD>
          <TD>9.00</TD>
          <TD>1.2</TD>
          <TD><INPUT type = "text" name = "notes"></TD>
        </TR>
        </TABLE>
DOM;

    $dom_ChangeResults = new DOMDocument();
    $dom_ChangeResults->loadHTML($domText); //Load the current changes as HTML String
    $dom_TableTags = $dom_ChangeResults->getElementsByTagName("table"); //Check table data tags for Full time to PartTime Change
    $rows = $dom_TableTags->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

    /*** loop over the table rows ***/
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
            /*** get each column by tag name ***/
            $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
            /*** echo the values ***/
            echo $cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />';
            echo $cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />';
            echo $cols->item(2)->nodeValue;
            echo '<hr />';
    }
```

**EDIT**

To work with data with one `<tr>` element:

```
$dom_ChangeResults = new DOMDocument();
$dom_ChangeResults->loadHTML($domText); //Load the current changes as HTML String
//$dom_TableTags = $dom_ChangeResults->getElementsByTagName("tr"); //Check table data tags for Full time to PartTime Change
$rows = $dom_ChangeResults->getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

Comment: You are right It is returning the EMPTY list. But You have modified my HTML file. I don't have any TABLE tag in my HTML Text. Can you please modify your code, to use the HTML Text as I posted on question? THank you very much

Comment: This worked Thank you Very much. I didn't knew that capitalization matters in PHP. New thing I learnt today.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through your `<tr>` elements, not `<td>`:

```
$dom_ChangeResults = new DOMDocument();
$dom_ChangeResults->loadHTML($domText); //Load the current changes as HTML String
$rows = $dom_ChangeResults->getElementsByTagName("tr");

/*** loop over the table rows ***/
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    /*** get each column by tag name ***/
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    /*** echo the values ***/
    echo $cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />';
    echo $cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />';
    echo $cols->item(2)->nodeValue;
    echo '<hr />';
}
```

Comment: If I do the above $rows on the third line will contain Nothing. SO its not entering the FOREACH loop at all.

Comment: @RealCoder, `$rows` will contain your single `<tr>` element. See demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c2e120ee2ab95e5309a3061a3ab556ff42c7ae02